# how to remove particular css styles of third party js file in reactjs

Tags: css, reactjs

Im using react-materialize for card, button , etc. 
And for another usage i use react bootstrap table.
Now the problem is React-Bootstrap contains its first columns as checkboxes, But  due to some css styles in react-materialize.min.css file, checkbox is getting hidden.

I want to remove only two properties in react-materialize.min.css, can anyone tell me how to overwrite or remove those styles?

Comment: Try to avoid the use of important. Use id's or specificity to overwrite the classes.

Answer (score 0):

Try using !important to override the styling in your stylesheet.

Note: The selectors should be same for the both the styles.